# Implementing CTCP commands in an IRC bot (Haskell)

Tags: haskell, irc, bots

I have followed the tutorial on the Haskell wiki about i[mplementing an IRC bot.](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Roll_your_own_IRC_bot) and everything worked out fine. But once I started extending it, I realised that It would need to respond to CTCP requests from other users for commands like version and ping. These commands work for the server but not for the bot.

I read the rfc's for [CTCP](http://www.irchelp.org/irchelp/rfc/ctcpspec.html) and for [IRC clients](http://www.irchelp.org/irchelp/rfc/rfc2812.txt) but they are not very useful.
I did the following, but I don't think it is the required message:

```
write "PRIVMSG" (sender++"\001VERSION Haskellbot : v1.0 : GHCi\001")
```

This only asked for version information from the sender. So how do I go about implementing the return message for CTCP requests and other CTCP requests in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon closer inspection of the CTCP rfc, I solved it with:

```
write "NOTICE" (sender++"\001VERSION Haskellbot : v1.0 : GHCi\001")
```

Comment: Note also that it's a protocol violation to automatically respond to a PRIVMSG with another PRIVMSG (and to automatically respond to a NOTICE at all) - these rules are designed to prevent infinite response loops between clients.